# Wondering why k value is different within IF condition

Tags: java

I am studying for coding interview. So, I am trying to solve problems on  "Cracking the coding Interview" book

This is the solution code on Github: https://github.com/careercup/CtCI-6th-Edition/blob/master/Java/Ch%2002.%20Linked%20Lists/Q2_02_Return_Kth_To_Last/QuestionA.java

Could you please tell me why k value can be 1 in "if" condition when printKthToLast(LinkedListNode head, 0)? The k value is 0 within printKthToLast method except for if condition.

```
public static int printKthToLast(LinkedListNode head, int k) {
    if (head == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    int index = printKthToLast(head.next, k) + 1;
    if (index == k) {
        System.out.println(k + "th to last node is " + head.data);
    }
    return index;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because at the line

```
int index = printKthToLast(head.next, k) + 1;
```

You add `1` to the result of the next call. So the last call to `printKthToLast` will return `0`, the second to last will return `1`, the third to last `2` and so on.